# string indices must be integers when using python with json

Tags: python, json

I want to print the ip addresses from jobs.json but I am getting the error 'string indices must be integers'

Here is my python code:

```
import json

f = open('jobs.json')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()

for item in data["Jobs"]:
print(item["ip"])
```

And here is the Jobs.json file:

```
{
"Jobs": {
    "Carpenter": {
        "ip": "123.1432.515",
        "address": ""
    },
    "Electrician": {
        "ip": "643.452.234",
        "address": "mini-iad.com"
    },
    "Plumber": {
        "ip": "151.101.193",
        "Address": "15501 Birch St"
    },
    "Mechanic": {
        "ip": "218.193.942",
        "Address": "Yellow Brick Road"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`data["Company"]` is a dictionary, so you're iterating over the keys (which are strings). Use `data["Company"].values()`:

```py
import json

with open("company.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

for item in data["Company"].values():
    print(item["ip"])
```

Prints:

```
142.250.115.139

151.101.193
```

Answer (score 0):

`data["Company"]` returns a dictionary. When iterating over that, you will get string keys for `item`, since that's what you get by default when iterating over a dictionary. Then you try to do `item["ip"]`, where `item` is "Google" for example, which causes your error.

You want to iterate the values of the dictionary instead:

```
for item in data["Company"].values():
    print(item["ip"])
```